# Should we include private methods in @covers in PHP code coverage

Tags: php, tdd, code-coverage

I was wondering if it is mandatory to use include @covers for private functions. Personally, I am against it since it would break encapsulation. And if you are practicing clean code, you would probably have a lot of private methods that you don't need your tests to see. What are the arguments in favor and against this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should focus on testing behavior, as exposed by public methods, and not be concerned with private methods which may change often during refactoring.  In my experience, I've found the use of code coverage tools to be more harmful than good, as it distracts from the core principles of TDD and often leads to developers gaming the metrics.

Comment: I agree. I find that code coverage is not a good metric of quality since some classes are not meant to be testable, eg: the layers near Databases, UI, Files, etc. And in my experience, I find a lot of TDD newbies trying to achieve 100% code coverage by exposing private methods and using awkward mocks. 

I could go on about it all day but that is not my concern. So in a scenario where we are working on a huge-ish project with multiple teams, where some code coverage is required, is there a way in PHP to avoid using @covers for private methods?